# GitHub API V3 list pull request assignees and pull request aprovals

Tags: github-api, pull-request

I'm currently using GitHub as a scm. I'm currently building a tool around it but came across some issues. Is there any way to check the pull request assignees and who approved the pull request?

In bitbucket it is really easy to do so, but using GitHub I do not see where to do it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a pull request's assignee by using our Issues API:

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues

Specifically, this endpoint:

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue

Since the Multiple Assignees API is still in preview mode, you will need to explicitly pass this custom media type in the Accept Header:

application/vnd.github.cerberus-preview+json

Omitting this header from the request will not show the multiple assignees for an Issue or Pull Request.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/issues/9355 \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.cerberus-preview+json" \ 
The payload should look something like this, including both assignees

{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/issues/9355",
  "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular",
  "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/issues/9355/labels{/name}",
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/issues/9355/comments",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/issues/9355/events",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9355",
  "id": 161102291,
  "number": 9355,
  "title": "fix(HTTP/XhrBackend): correctly set the status code on errors",
  "user": {
    "login": "vicb",
    "id": 248818,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/248818?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/vicb",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/vicb/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "labels": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/labels/cla:%20yes",
      "name": "cla: yes",
      "color": "009800"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/labels/comp:%20http",
      "name": "comp: http",
      "color": "c7def8"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/labels/pr_action:%20review",
      "name": "pr_action: review",
      "color": "fbca04"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/labels/type:%20bug",
      "name": "type: bug",
      "color": "EEEEEE"
    }
  ],
  "state": "open",
  "locked": false,
  "assignee": {
    "login": "jeffbcross",
    "id": 463703,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/463703?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/jeffbcross",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "milestone": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/milestones/62",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/angular/angular/milestones/2.0.0-rc.3",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/milestones/62/labels",
    "id": 1831054,
    "number": 62,
    "title": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "description": "",
    "creator": {
      "login": "IgorMinar",
      "id": 216296,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/216296?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/IgorMinar",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/IgorMinar/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "open_issues": 25,
    "closed_issues": 14,
    "state": "open",
    "created_at": "2016-06-15T23:19:22Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-20T17:55:29Z",
    "due_on": null,
    "closed_at": null
  },
  "comments": 0,
  "created_at": "2016-06-20T01:21:21Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-06-20T01:21:22Z",
  "closed_at": null,
  "pull_request": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/pulls/9355",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9355",
    "diff_url": "https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9355.diff",
    "patch_url": "https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9355.patch"
  },
  "body": "fixes #9329\r\nfixes angular/http#54\r\n\r\n@robwormald @jeffbcross could one of you please review ? Thanks",
  "closed_by": null,
  "assignees": [
    {
      "login": "jeffbcross",
      "id": 463703,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/463703?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/jeffbcross",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/jeffbcross/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    {
      "login": "robwormald",
      "id": 534930,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/534930?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/robwormald",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/robwormald/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    }
  ]
}
```